# En R, dividir dataframe por rangos de valores de columna. Hacer operaciones de forma iterativa y pegar resultados

Tags: r, loops

tengo un versión muy simplificada de un dataframe A bastante grande (50 columnas y 1000000 lineas):

```
Palabra      Frecuencia  Numero
hola(1.4)    0.15        1
amigo(1.2)   0.67        2
sol(0.3)     0.85        7
hola(7.1)    0.4         3
hola(5.1)    0.44        4
```

Quiero hacer operaciones primero dividiendo A en 4 sub dataframes de acuerdo a los valores de la columna "Frecuencia", que van entre 0 y 1, agrupando los valores en 4 canastas de frecuencia de tamaño 0.25. Esto se puede hacer con dplyr usando "group_by". En cada una de las 4 sub dataframes generadas, quiero crear sub sub dataframes que contengan todas las lineas que contengan una palabra específica como "hola" en la columna "Palabra". Esto lo sé hacer con filter y grepl. Luego  quiero hacer operaciones matemáticas sobre estas sub sub dataframes, como por ejemplo:

```
op1 = mean(Numero)
op2 = nrow(Numero)
```

Luego de juntar op1 con op2 con cbind y realizar un par de operaciones simples, genero nuevas dataframes como esta:

```
Palabra      op1    op2  Canasta
hola         0.42   2    [0.25, 0.5]
```

Finalmente (y esto es lo mas importante), quiero hacer este proceso de forma iterativa para cada canasta y palabra, y generar una nueva dataframe que me pegue ("append") las lineas generadas para las diferentes canastas. Algo así resultaría:

```
Palabra      op1    op2  Canasta
hola         0.21   3    [0, 0.25]
amigo        0.3    5    [0, 0.25]
sol          4.2    6    [0, 0.25]
hola         0.42   2    [0.25, 0.5] # esta linea corresponde al ejemplo de sub sub dataframe
amigo        0.32   2    [0.25, 0.5]
sol          0.11   7    [0.25, 0.5]
hola         0.72   2    [0.5, 0.75] 
amigo        0.52   2    [0.5, 0.75]
sol          0.1    3    [0.5, 0.75]
hola         0.72   5    [0.75, 1] 
amigo        0.49   7    [0.75, 1]
sol          0.10   1    [0.75, 1]
```

He visto que lapply puede ayudar en la iteración pero no me queda claro cómo en este ejemplo. Quizás haya alguna forma mucho mas directa y fácil de hacerlo. Lo que más me importa es la dataframe final.

Answer (score 2):

Si las operaciones que deseas hacer te darán siempre como resultado un única valor (una medida resumen), puedes ontener lo que deseas usando la función `summarize` de `dplyr`.

```
tu_tabla %>% 
      mutate(Canasta = cut(Frecuencia, seq(0, 1, .25), include.lowest = T, right = T)) %>% 
      group_by(Canasta, Palabra) %>% 
      summarize(op1 = mean(Numero), op2 = length(Numero))
```